# How to access textbox value of $mdDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using following code to prompt the dialog box and there is one textbox on dialog box . How can i access the value inside the textbox when i click the cancel button (here renamed in "Create New Account") ?

**this is my code where I am using dialog box**

```
var confirm =
    $mdDialog.prompt()
        .title('Mobile no. not found')
        .textContent('Entered mobile no. has no associated account.')
        .placeholder('Mobile number')
        .ariaLabel('Mobile')
        .initialValue(mobile)
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .parent(angular.element(document.body))
        .ok('Continue')
        .cancel('Create New Account');
```

**Here I am catching the event**

```
$mdDialog
    .show(confirm)
    .then(function(result) {
        var jsonData = {"mobile":result};
        msApi.request(
            'login.credentials@save',
            headers,
            jsonData,
            // SUCCESS
            function (response) {
                if(response.error == 1){
                    showPrompt(ev,result);
                }
                if(response.error == 0) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if((response.data.device == 0 ) && (response.data.mpin > 0) && (response.data.otp > 0) ) {
                        $state.go('app.pages_auth_verify-otp');
                    }
                    if((response.data.device == 1 ) && (response.data.mpin > 0) && (response.data.otp == 0) ) {
                        $state.go('app.pages_auth_verify-mpin');
                    }     
                }
            },
            // ERROR
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        )
    }, function() {
        alert();
    });
```

Comment: err, `result` IS what the user wrote in the textbox...

Comment: what if I want to use result in alert(). see above I added alert(); in second function.

Comment: so you want to access the value of the textbox when the user click cancel, i don't know if it's possible. I think it's better to write your own dialog...

Comment: hmm. thanks @Crisim